# Kite is not working VS code but showning no error

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, kite

I have installed both kite extention and engine and it is showing that everything is ok but autocompletion doesn't work in VS code as you can see below:

[image]

I have installed latest versions of kite and vs code in previous I used tabnine.